# Set parent style from child element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a custom dropdown field. Following is my code:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const listItems = list.getElementsByTagName('p');

document.querySelector('#category').onclick = function() {
  // Able to show the .list DOM element
  list.style.display = 'block';
}

Array.from(listItems)
  .forEach(function(listItem) {
    listItem.onclick = function() {

      // Unable to hide the .list DOM element
      list.style.display = 'none';

      // .listItem's value is getting logged
      console.log(listItem.getAttribute('value'));
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" id="category" name="category">
  <div class="trigger">
    <p class="selected-category">Category</p>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <p value="">None</p>
    <p value="1">harum inventore</p>
    <p value="2">dolorem voluptatem</p>
    <p value="3">dolores consectetur</p>
    <p value="4">velit culpa</p>
    <p value="5">beatae nulla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not exactly sure where it is going wrong as I'm able to set the `list`'s `style` attribute to to `display: block` but I'm unable to set it back to `display: none` even though I'm trying to do the same thing from two different places.

I'm pretty new to Javascript. This might be a duplicate but I honestly tried looking up and trying as many solutions as possible. But none seemed to work. So apologies in advance.

Comment: `p` elements do not have a `value` attribute, thus **your HTML is invalid**. Use `data-value` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was working right, but because your parent and child had click event listeners on them, you were hiding and showing the list back.

Here you can find more about event bubbling: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const listItems = list.getElementsByTagName('p');

// Overlapping event listener 1
document.querySelector('#category').onclick = function() {
  list.style.display = 'block';
}

Array.from(listItems)
  .forEach(function(listItem) {
    // Overlapping event listener 2
    listItem.onclick = function(event) {
      // to fix double event issue, you have to prevent its bubbling up
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      list.style.display = 'none';
      // Uncomment the debugger here and you will see that this code works right
      // debugger;
      console.log(listItem.getAttribute('data-value'));
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" id="category" name="category">
  <div class="trigger">
    <p class="selected-category">Category</p>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <p data-value="">None</p>
    <p data-value="1">harum inventore</p>
    <p data-value="2">dolorem voluptatem</p>
    <p data-value="3">dolores consectetur</p>
    <p data-value="4">velit culpa</p>
    <p data-value="5">beatae nulla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on what's happening. This really helps. Cheers!

Comment: `p` elements do not have a `value` attribute, thus **the HTML is invalid**. Use `data-value` instead.

Comment: @connexo, that's true, but it's not related to the question issue.

Comment: @connexo what are the possible downsides of using `value` instead of `data-value`?

Comment: @ikartik90, the downside is that you rely on the browser's implementation details to handle that invalid HTML. Therefore you may have a working version in Chrome, but Firefox or older Edge may throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The event listener of your parent `#category` element is executed every time you click one of it's child elements. You can prevent the click event from bubbling up to the parent element by using the [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method on the child elements' listener.

Also, as [@connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744304/connexo) mentioned in the comments, `<p>` elements do not have a `value` attribute. You are probably looking for a `<ul>` element with `<li>` children.

---

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list li');

document.querySelector('#category').onclick = function() {
  list.style.display = 'block';                     // Able to show the .list DOM element
}

Array.from(listItems)
  .forEach(function(listItem) {
    listItem.onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // prevent parent event listener from being executed
      list.style.display = 'none';                  // Unable to hide the .list DOM element
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.list {display: none; list-style: none;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" id="category" name="category">
  <div class="trigger">
    <p class="selected-category">Category</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>None</li>
    <li>harum inventore</li>
    <li>dolorem voluptatem</li>
    <li>dolores consectetur</li>
    <li>velit culpa</li>
    <li>beatae nulla</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `p` elements do not have a `value` attribute, thus **the HTML is invalid**. Use `data-value` instead.